# Coldfusion 7 and jquery ajax - need help with response

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I am calling a remote CFC in ajax using Coldfusion 7. The CFC is set to return a value of 0 when all is successfully done. I have appended the URL to the CFC with "&returnformat=plain" and I have also set the returnformat attribute of the cfc to "plain".

But everytime I do the cfc call, I get the response back as a WDDX packet instead of plain text. I have tried omitting the "&returnformat=plain" from the URL string and lots of other things, but nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Gary

Comment: Can you post code for jQuery AJAX request and the CFC?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `returnformat` is added in [CF8](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_f_21.html#2852457), not available to [CF7](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000263.htm#2852457).

In this case, you might want to use this workaround:

in /remote/myFunc.cfm:

```
<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly="yes">
<cfoutput>#createObject("component","myComp").myFunc(URL.param1,URL.param2)#</cfoutput>
```

FYI, CF7 has no clue what is JSON neither, so you'll need to use 3rd party udf/cfc.  If you need one, see: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2010/11/3/Best-JSON-option-for-folks-not-running-ColdFusion-9

Time to upgrade your CF. :)